# Gitlab - .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, gitlab

What I am trying to achieve is to build an image of my project and push it to my own registry. I already set-up the CI/CD variables manually and they are proper but I am getting the following errors.

```
image: docker:20.10.16

build:
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.16-dind
      alias: docker
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login "$DOCKER_REGISTRY" -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" -p "$DOCKER_PASSWORD"
    - docker build -t "$IMAGE":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" .
    - docker push "$IMAGE":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
```

WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth": dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables

Comment: looks like your $DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is incorrect. Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth"
there's no such domain, unless you want to use custom dns